# Can this set becomes a Banach space?

Tags: derivatives, banach-spaces

Given a set $B=\{x | x:[t_0, T]\rightarrow \mathbb{R}^n,$ $x$ is a differentiable function on $[t_0, T]-\{t_1,...,t_M\}$ and $x(t^{+}_k)=\lim \limits_{t \rightarrow t^{+}_k} x(t)$ and $x(t^{-}_k)=\lim \limits_{t \rightarrow t^{-}_k} x(t)$ exists with the condition $x(t^{-}_k)=x(t_k)$ and $x(t_0)=\lim \limits_{t\rightarrow t^{-}_0}x(t)\}.$ Then my question is whether $B$ is a banach space on real field? Further whether it means all differentiable functions on $[t_0, T]$ will be included in $B?$

Comment: What norm are you using?

Comment: Clearly, $B$ is closed under linear combinations (though I think you mean that $x(t_{0})=\lim_{t\rightarrow t_{0}^{+}}x(t)$), so the next important question is what the norm would be on such a space. Then, we would need to verify whether or not $B$ is complete with respect to this norm.

Comment: $\|x\|=\sup \limits_{t\in [t_0, T]} \|x(t)\|$ where $\|x(t)\|$ is an Euclidean norm on real space $\mathbb{R}^n$

Comment: No, it's not a Banach space, as you could approximate a non-differentiable function by differentiable ones.

Comment: If i take x to be almost everywhere differentiable function on $[t_0, T]-\{t_1,...,t_M\}?$